# Updating DOMAttr value with URL results in parameters being lost unless htmlentities() is used. Why?

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I am trying to modify links in a string containing HTML but am finding the modified URLs are missing parameters.

Example:

```
$html = '
<p>
    <a href="http://example.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar">Example 1</a>
</p>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//a/@href') as $node) {
    echo '$node->nodeValue: ' . $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    $newValue = 'http://example2.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar';
    echo '$newValue: ' . $newValue . PHP_EOL;
    $node->nodeValue = $newValue;
    echo '$node->nodeValue: ' . $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
$node->nodeValue: http://example.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar
$newValue: http://example2.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar
$node->nodeValue: http://example2.com?foo=bar
```

As you can see, the second parameter is lost after updating the `nodeValue`.

While experimenting I tried changing `$newValue` to this:

```
$newValue = htmlentities('http://example2.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar');
```

And the output then becomes:

```
$node->nodeValue: http://example.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar
$newValue: http://example2.com?foo=bar&amp;bar=foobar
$node->nodeValue: http://example2.com?foo=bar&bar=foobar
```

Why is it necessary for the new node value to be run through `htmlentities()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersands are reserved characters in XML/HTML — they begin character references. If you try to write them directly to strings in the DOM things often blow up because the DOM doesn't know what you're trying to say. When you use `htmlentities()` first it encodes the "&" and everyone is speaking the same language again.

Fortunately there's no need for `htmlentities()` at all. Instead of setting the `nodeValue` directly, use the [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) method of the href's owner.

---

#### Rather than:

```
$node->nodeValue = $newValue;
```

#### Use:

```
$node->ownerElement->setAttribute('href', $newValue);
```

---

Directly manipulating strings in the DOM can lead to problems that won't even necessarily manifest the same across systems. I didn't lose parameters with your example, I lost the entire URL.

I highly recommend sticking with setters whenever possible.